# What is the purpose of a "framed" switch?

Tags: electrical

I'm replacing the switches throughout my house and came across [this one today](http://www.buyhardwaresupplies.com/hardware_supplies.cfm?t=5&itemNumber=3293388). What is the value of it being "framed" (it seems like that's the only difference between it and the most basic switch)?

Can I just replace it with [this one](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-15-Amp-Single-Pole-AC-Quiet-Switch-White-R72-05601-2WS/100058788).

Comment: It appears that the _framed_ ones have a ground screw and the unframed ones like http://www.buyhardwaresupplies.com/hardware_supplies.cfm?t=5&itemNumber=31964 don't. The Leviton Decora Switch you link to is also framed and has a ground screw. It is a proper replacement if you would like that kind of switch over the other type.

Comment: @DanD. I don't think that's it. If it were then all the other switches on the linked page w/a ground would be framed too; no? I think it's a higher grade switch @$2+; elsewhere it talks of a solid frame. On the commercial side we called them spec-grade. It's what you put in "nicer" jobs and public works projects.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @ChiefTwoPencils, excuse the ignorance, but what is the practical value of having a higher grade switch? Do you agree with DanD that it would be ok to replace it with the Leviton Decora Switch? I feel like it was put in for some purpose since there was an adjacent switch that was "unframed". I'm really stumped here.

Comment: If it's helpful at all, the switch in question is attached to a garbage disposal and has two red wires connected to it. The other non-framed adjacent switch I mentioned is attached to a light and had two black wires going into it (pretty clear there's some color-coding issues with the wiring).

Comment: [This](http://www.hubbell-wiring.com/press/pdfs/h5254.pdf) is a different company but will give you an idea of specification(spec)-grade devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, cheaper residential grade switches are "framed" like this, and have a slimmer toggle, while commercial "spec-grade" switches have a larger unframed toggle.

This is a Leviton spec-grade 20A switch:

[image]

While this is the framed residential switch from the original question:

[image]

Decora switches, like this, are also typically spec-grade:

[image]

None of this has anything to do with grounding. The only switches without ground screws are switches specifically to be used as replacements for  non-grounding devices.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I still don't understand, though - what is the practical difference between the framed and non-framed switches? What purpose does the framing serve?

Comment: @gavinci, I guess I had the framed and non-framed switches switched, I was going off price. The practical difference is just the over all quality. Cheapo 15 A switches feel, look, and basically are crap. It's the same when you talk about quality vs budget tools, drum heads, furniture...I think you get the picture; they're plain better.

Comment: So, do you see commercial-grade as spec-grade? IIRC there's commercial grade, which is higher quality than resi, but then there's "spec-grade". We kept commercial-grade for the general case on the truck but bought spec-grade as needed where spec-ed.

Comment: @gavinci, the only practical difference is like Chief said, the cheaper switches have a cheaper toggle and therefore feel cheaper.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, I know that spec-grade is a certain level of quality. Some manufacturers do have that, plus "commercial grade" and even others. All I know is if I ask for spec-grade I am getting the better quality devices. Even in commercial settings I can't see any pracitcal difference in commercial grade devices.

Comment: This answer would be alright if the question was about cheap vs spec-grade... but the question is "what is the purpose of a framed switch?" which this doesn't answer at all.

Comment: @gregmac, Well, the frame has no purpose. I DID answer in that cheap switches have the frame and spec-grade does not. If you feel that deserves a downvote more power to ya. What more are you looking for?

Comment: Specifically saying it has no purpose would be fine. I downvoted only because this was accepted but I didn't feel it actually answered the question, and I was genuinely curious myself as I'd never thought about it. (Eg: you can get spec-grade framed toggles, so simply saying framed = residential, non-framed = spec grade is misleading).

Comment: @gregmac, that's your opinion, and it's fine. In my many years in the trade this has been the rule. If you can find spec-grade switches with the frame that's awesome, I haven't seen any.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means the case of the switch is molded around the bezel of the switch. Levitron seems to use this language to describe its "commercial-quality" switches.

Comment: Leviton also has commercial grade switches without frames. I think the frame may just be a cosmetic detail (?).  eg CS120-2W is a commercial switch without a frame.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99% sure it means there is a raised frame at the base of the actual toggle or not. I have 2 boxes in front of me right now, framed vs unframed. The framed has a small raised area around the based of the toggle (plastic), while the unframed does not. Not sure if this is purely cosmetic or if it adds any strength to the switch.

Also note both of these are marked as "commercial" grade (Hubbel from Lowes)

Comment: I agree, this presence or not of a frame around the toggle doesn't seem to relate to "quality" at all. If you compare Leviton http://www.leviton.com/en/products/CS120-2W and http://www.leviton.com/en/products/54521-2W they are both "commercial" grade and have almost identical descriptions except for the frame (or lack of)